# Python3. How to check if a suffix is in some of the words in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using python3 and coming across this question. Say I have a list

```
L = ["money", "fame", "popularity"]
```

I want to check if there is any word in `L` that contains `"pop"`. I know that if `L` is a string, e.g. if `L = "I want to be popular"`, then I can just do `"pop" in l`, and the boolean value will be returned. But now `L` is a list, how can I check if any word in this list contains `"pop"` then? (not using a loop if possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `any()` to return a `True` for any match case:

```
any('pop' in x for x in L)
```

**Code**:

```
L = ["money", "fame", "popularity"]

print(any('pop' in x for x in L))
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter with lambda function

```
L = ["populate", "position", "popcorn"]
didContainPop = len(list(filter(lambda x: "pop" in x, L))) != 0
print(didContainPop)
```

Comment: One could use `next` rather than `len` of `list` to check that the iterator has at least one item. This would avoid creating a list that could be as long as L.

Comment: @DanD. Hey I am also learning python. I unable to understand your point, can you please give a little illustration for further I will take care of it. Thanks.

Comment: I mean that `next(it, default) == default` when it is empty otherwise the result is the first item from it. This along with using a sentinel object results in `o = object()`, `did_contain = next(filter(..., L), o) is not o`. The fresh object `o` can't be an item in the list as we just created it.